# Allow only x number of form fields to be filled in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very noob question, I have a form with input fields. The form has 10 fields, and the user needs to enter from 1-3 (one being most preferred, to 3 being last choice). After 3 have been filled, I want to either disable all other fields, or just disallow any further input and give an error.

I've got the counting up working, but i can't restrict or pop an error.

here's the code,

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    $("#choices").on('keyup change', function() {
        var maxAllowed = 3;
        var number = 0;
        $(this).find('input, textarea').each(function () {
            //if (number < maxAllowed && this.value !== '') 
            if (this.value !== '') 
            {
                $('.input_count').val(number++); 
            }        
        });
    });
    
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form method="post"  id="userForm" role="form">
                <h3>Selection form</h3>
                <p>Fill in your choices from 1-3 (please select only three).</p>
                <div id="choices">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Recreational fishing">Recreational fishing</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" size="3"  name="form[Recreational fishing]" id="Recreational fishing" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Recreational boating">Recreational boating</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" size="3"  name="form[Recreational boating]" id="Recreational boating" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Sightseeing tourist">Sightseeing tourist</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" size="3"  name="form[Sightseeing tourist]" id="Sightseeing tourist" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Exercise">Exercise</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" size="3"  name="form[Exercise]" id="Exercise" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Picnics BBQ">Picnics/BBQ</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" size="3"  name="form[Picnics BBQ]" id="Picnics BBQ" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Sunsets and socialising">Sunsets and socialising</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" size="3"  name="form[Sunsets and socialising]" id="Sunsets and socialising" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Bird watching">Bird watching</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" size="3"  name="form[Bird watching]" id="Bird watching" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="alert alert-info">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="counter">Counter:</label>
                        <input class="input_count form-control" type="text" id="counter" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="form[Submit]" id="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

.... or here's a fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/Flocktome/wmdnnm4j/

any thoughts would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not directly relevant to the question but... wouldn't it be better to use check boxes?

Comment: Even better, organize the form by favorite rather than by choice.  Have the form consist of three lines, 1st, 2nd, 3rd. In each line  put independent list of choices in the drop down menus or a select box.  Then all you have to check is that they are distinct.

Comment: you can disable rest of the fields

Comment: Can't do it guys, this form replicates a printable form in it's design and function, but that's a very nice valid point. Either use 3 checkboxes (or radio) groups with the list in each, or 3 drop down menu items. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. I have found number of fields filled using `filter` function and disabled other fields using `each`, when the maximum number of fields allowed are filled. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmdnnm4j/8/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    $("#choices").on('keyup', function() {
        var maxAllowed = 3;        
        var els = $(this).find('input, textarea');
        var elsFilled = els.filter(function(i,el){ return el.value!="" }).length;
        if(elsFilled==maxAllowed)
          els.each(function(i,el){ if(el.value=="") el.disabled = true; });
        else
          els.each(function(i,el){ if(el.value=="") el.disabled = false; });  
   });  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
                $("#choices").on('keyup change', function() {
                    var maxAllowed = 4;
                    var number_done = 0;
                    $(this).find('input, textarea').removeAttr('disabled');
                        $(this).find('input, textarea').each(function () {
                            //if (number < maxAllowed && this.value !== '') 
                            if (this.value !== '') 
                            {
                                $('.input_count').val(++number_done); 
                            }       
                        });
                    if( number_done >= maxAllowed){
                        $(this).find('input,textarea').filter(function(){
                            if($(this).val()== '')
                                   return true;
                            return false;
                        }).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    }
                });

            });
```

Here the max allowed is set to 4.because of you counter field.Which should be ingnored i think for the test purpose.Once this field is removed the maxallwoed can be set as 3

Comment: I found if i set maxAllowed to 3, and number_done to -1 then i still can see my count as "3" and select 3. Thanks for the input.

Comment: This is same as what I said. 3- (-1) = 4- 0 .
I mean to say that as per your requirement that maximum allowed field is 3,so the maxAllowed should be 3. But as you display a field for count. which also get claculated as the number of non empty field, so I suggest you increase the maxAllowed to 4.I hope it is clear now.Thanks